# Python camera.rotation_euler problem

Tags: python, camera

I cannot figure out why the following line of code throws the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rotation_euler'"

```
bpy.context.scene.camera.rotation_euler =(0,0,0)
```

Comment: If the scene has no camera then `scene.camera is None` it can also be set to `None`  Having the value `None` is the error.

Comment: @batFINGER - the camera exists, and when I put the code at the beginning of the script it still throws the error.  So it's not being set to None at runtime.  Suggestions?

Comment: Is it assigned to the scene, ie check the scene properties panel or `C.scene.camera` in the console.  The error message implies it is not set. _There can be a zillion cameras in the scene, only one (or none) at any point in timeline is the "scene camera"_

Comment: As shown in answer below... To set `scene.camera = scene.objects.get("Camera")` will set it to camera named "Camera" if it exists, else `None`.

Answer (score 1):

If the camera exist but this is NOT set; then you get the error

[image: error]

you must set the camera

[image: setting the camera]